# Issue with Autolayout and UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a UIView that contains a UItableView. I pinned the Table View to the corners of the view. Within my cell I have I have 1 UILabel with number of lines set to 0 and Line Breaks set to word wrap. I have the UILabel pinned to the 4 corners of the content view inside my cell. Also preferred width set to 300.

When I log out height and width I get 0.

Picture of what I get:

[image]

Here's my code for calculating the height of the label:

```
   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        return [self heightForCommentCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];   
    }

    -(ECDCommentCell *)commentCellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

         ECDCommentCell *cell = (ECDCommentCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:commentCellIdentifier];

        [cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [cell.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];

        [cell.contentLabel.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [cell.contentLabel.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];

        [self configureCommentCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)configureCommentCell:(ECDCommentCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        PFObject *commentObject = [self.commentResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //=============== Configure Comment Text
        NSString *commentText = [commentObject objectForKey:@"content"];
        [cell.contentLabel setText:commentText];
    }




    - (CGFloat)heightForCommentCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static ECDCommentCell *sizingCell = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sizingCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:commentCellIdentifier];
        });

        [self configureCommentCell:sizingCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        return [self calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:sizingCell];
    }


    - (CGFloat)calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell:(UITableViewCell *)sizingCell {
        sizingCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(sizingCell.bounds));
        [sizingCell setNeedsLayout];
        [sizingCell layoutIfNeeded];

        CGSize size = [sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
        return size.height + 1.0f; // Add 1.0f for the cell separator height
    }
```

If I add a fix height lets say of 60 I get:

[image]

Comment: Sorry i can't understand the picture. Probably i can help you as i face to this issue recently. But, it is important i understand what is happening.

Comment: With the picture their are 3 rows being returned. The Table view have the red border, the cell have the blue border, and UIlabel have the green border. The returned height I'm getting for the is zero for both height and width.

Comment: I added a picture showing me forcing the height vs calculating it with autolayout

Comment: @MatteoGobbi I added a picture showing me forcing the height vs calculating it with autolayout

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple mistake. Forgot to synthesis my label.